# Spring Cloud Config Server - application.properties overriding profile properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-profiles

I am trying to understand why a profile-specific property is overridden by the base application.properties within my Spring Cloud Config. I am using Spring Boot 2.4. Here is the minimal product reproducing the issue: [github.com/semagnum/spring-config-server-poc-issue](https://github.com/semagnum/spring-config-server-poc-issue)

Spring Cloud Config Client is enabled for my test app. When I call my config server, it retrieves a String array property:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "profiles": [
    "dev"
  ],
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "classpath:/myapp-dev.properties",
      "source": {
        "my.security.scope[0]": "api://MY_APP/.default"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "classpath:/myapp.properties",
      "source": {
        "my.security.scope[0]": "default"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This string array property is not defined at all in the client's application files, no `spring.cloud.config.override` properties defined. When run and I retrieve the scope value, it returns "default", *not* dev's "api:MY_APP/.default". Why is it picking the non-dev one instead of the dev one, which I would expect to override it?